# react native released apk crush on launch

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

i get no errors when i compile the APK in release but after i install it it crashes  instant on load. Here are my packages:

```
{
  "name": "etwow_rent",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.1.2",
    "bundle": "^2.1.0",
    "haversine": "^1.1.0",
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "^0.57.1",
    "react-native-camera": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.22.0",
    "react-native-qrcode-scanner": "^1.1.0",
    "react-navigation": "^2.18.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.48.0",
    "react-native-bundle": "0.0.4",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.5.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: you can add crashltics to get the error and resolve it accordingly , without knowing the error it would be difficult to resolve the issue

Comment: +1 above. You need some tools like bugsnag or appcenter to gather more details. Else you can manually try to remove/add back dependencies to see if any of them causes error, but it's more difficult.

Comment: Add also gradle file here. Run the apk on connected device then run `adb logcat`, get the error from there and add it to your question.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you forgot one of the steps for generating Signed APK ,Here is full Documentation of Generating Signed APK https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android
You can go through it.